# AdSense ads not showing in php script page

Tags: javascript, php, adsense

I'm working on one PHP script for independence day. the problem is that Adsense ads are showing in homepage (i.e http://happyimages.org ) but the Ads are not showing in PHP script page. (i.e http://happyimages.org/?by=Jamal ) . Please do help me out. My Adsense is account is non-hosted and is fully approved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="canonical" href="index.html" itemprop="url" /> <title> Happy Independence Day 2018</title>
<meta name="description" content="Create Happy Independence Day Wishes, 15 August 2018, Happy Independence Day 2018 wishing website" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6xCkfaUUAew/W1gct0JohpI/AAAAAAAABbQ/Y7FuPrRg_s8dc4UuPelbpKxHNcRf-_tFwCLcBGAs/s1600/flag.jpg" sizes="32x32">
<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5b486eaae1ceeb001b842d49&product=sticky-share-buttons' async='async'></script>

<meta property="og:title" content=" Wishing You Happy Independence Day 2018" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="index.php" />
<meta property="og:image" content="happy-independence-day-15-august.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="640" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="415" />
<meta property="og:description" content="From TechnoVedant<?php

$n=$_GET['by'];

echo "$n"

?> 

Happy Independence Day Wishes, 15 August 2018, Make Happy Independence Day wish greetings card online #TechnoVedant" />


<meta name="twitter:description" content="Create Happy Independence Day Wishes 2018, 15 August 2018, Make Happy Independence Day wish greetings card online" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vdjmfpaVRvc/W1gfkky7jWI/AAAAAAAABbo/-H0Af3bR9XgdgITgpc0qtlCBg81eKh4RQCLcBGAs/s1600/happy-independence-day-15-august.png" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css ">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>


<body>



<div id="confetti"></div>
<div class="container my">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
 <center>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 300X50 Wishing Script -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:50px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-3743485334306324"
     data-ad-slot="3196563739"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<h1 style="display:none;"> Happy Independence Day Script </h1>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="msg-holder">
<div class="msg">
<?php

$n=$_GET['by'];

echo "$n"

?> </div>
</div>
<div class="msg2"> Wishing You </div>
<div class="msg3"> Happy Independence Day </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h6 class="myimg"> <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ph1Tl69E0aQ/W1ggs5HAw2I/AAAAAAAABb0/i5cuGX7cmucrspAqALK-vysex0ktsXpDgCLcBGAs/s1600/india-independence-day.png" class='img-responsive' alt="Happy Independence 2018"> </h6>
</div>
</div>
</div>




  <div align="center"><div align="center"><script language="JavaScript" src="http://clickmasters.mobie.in/Jss/effect/agve-loverain.red.js"></script></div></div>  <div align="center"><div id="mainDiv">    <marquee scrollamount="3" loop="infinite" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" scrolldelay="0"> <span style="background: #FF0000;padding: 1px 7px;font-size: large;font-weight: bold;color: #FFF8DC;margin: 0px 0px;border-radius: 40px;"><font color="#F0FFFF">Feel the pride of being the part of such a glorious nation. Here’s sending my warm patriotic wishes to make this day truly memorable. </font></span><span style="background:#0000FF;padding: 1px 7px;font-size: large;font-weight: bold;color: #FF0000;margin: 0px 0px;border-radius: 40px;"><font color="white">Independence is a Precious gift of God. May We Always Remain Independent A Very Happy Independence Day To You.</font></span><span style="background:    Pink;padding: 1px 7px;font-size: large;font-weight: bold;color: #00FF00;margin: 0px 0px;border-radius: 40px;"><font color="#000000">Happy Indian Independence Day 2018</font></span></marquee></div></div>



<div class="container myads">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="box">
<div class="row box2">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
<form method="get" class="form-inline myform">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control mytext" name="by" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
</div>
    <center>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 300X50 Wishing Script -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:50px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-3743485334306324"
     data-ad-slot="3196563739"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</center>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default mybtn">Create Wish</button>
</form>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
<div class="tt">
<span class="sb-title"> <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Share With Your Friends </span>
<span class="sb-share">
<div class="wp sb-icon"> <a href="whatsapp://send?text= From <?php

$n=$_GET['by'];

echo "*$n*"

?>
&#10;

%20Created%20Something%20Special%20Only%20For%20You%20Touch%20The%20Blue%20Line <?php echo $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>" target="_blank" title="Share this post on Whatsapp" class="whatsapp"> <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i> Whatsapp </a> </div>




</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container myads">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/bird.js"></script>


      <center>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 300X50 Wishing Script -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:50px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-3743485334306324"
     data-ad-slot="3196563739"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</center>


<script src="TechnoVedant.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="doodle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        doodle.init("jet.png");
    </script>

    <?php
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ads are visible on both links provided by you.

Comment: Are you sure? and which browser u using?

Comment: Checked on Google Chrome

Comment: ya I'm on Chrome but still not showing.

Comment: Check on other machine OR on with different network OR with any proxy

Comment: Than i guess it is the problem with my net. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see your ads on both of the pages.

Such problem occurs on newly added banner codes OR on newly introduced pages and by the time, it starts displaying in different locations.

You should try on other machine OR on different network OR with any proxy